# Watchify does not update when using Webstorm

Tags: gulp, webstorm, browserify, watchify

I am using watchify with gulp. When using notepad++ to edit source code, watchify works fine, but it does nothing when I edit with Jetbrain Webstorm 8.
Here is my gulpfile:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('watchify', function(){
    var bundler = browserify('./app/js/app.js', {
        debug: true,
        cache: {}, 
        packageCache: {}
        fullPaths: true
    });
    var watcher  = watchify(bundler);

    return watcher.on('update', function () { // When any files update
            console.log('Updating!');
            var updateStart = Date.now();
            watcher.bundle()
                .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/js'));
            console.log('Updated!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
        })
        .bundle() // Create the initial bundle when starting the task
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/js'));
});
```

Is there anyway to make watchify work with Webstorm ? 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Press Ctrl+S after edit.

Answer (score 4):

I posting this just for the sake of future searchers - I think the cause of that problem is **Enabled "Use safe write"**. After disabling problems seems to disappear.

https://github.com/substack/watchify/issues/179

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much, you just saved my life.